# Наращения числительных в датах

Tags: даты, наращение

Kак правильно написать: "Он уехал 20 мая, а 25 вернулся" или "Он уехал 20 мая, а 25-го вернулся"?

По правилам в датах нельзя применять наращения, как быть в данном случае?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно - второй вариант:

"Он уехал 20 мая, а 25-го вернулся".

Как только исчезает слово "месяц", то есть сам месяц, наращение необходимо.

То же и с годом, и с другим указанием при дате:

в октябре 17-го, в июне 41-го (если без тысяча девятьсот), а века пишутся римскими (без падежных наращений).

В справочнике Мильчина:

> ...Однако если слово год или название месяца опущено или поставлено
>   перед числом, падежное окончание рекомендуется наращивать. Напр.: в
>   мае, числа 20-го; год 1920-й; Грянул 1917-й; Концерт перенесли с 15
>   мая на 22-е; 20-го же апреля.

[**Подробно о наращениях**.](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1514821-kak-pravilno-oboznachit-padezh-imjon-chislitelnyh-napisannyh-chislom-sm.html)

[**Когда нужны буквенные наращения после цифр?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99)

[**А. Мильчин. Справочник издателя и автора.**](https://books.google.ru/books?id=dv-mC8T4fasC&pg=PT204&lpg=PT204&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80.:%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5,%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%2020-%D0%B3%D0%BE;%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%201920-%D0%B9;%20%D0%93%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%201917-%D0%B9;%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%2015%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%2022-%D0%B5;%2020-%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=X02ErpUYGS&sig=qg66LlyLGGGne-x6nTMt5sT97UM&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1s8nJtKHPAhWFnRoKHZ1XDeoQ6AEIKDAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80.%3A%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%2020-%D0%B3%D0%BE%3B%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%201920-%D0%B9%3B%20%D0%93%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%201917-%D0%B9%3B%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%2015%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%2022-%D0%B5%3B%2020-%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F&f=false)

Да, ещё уточнение к цитате:

> ...когда при указании даты название месяца или года опущено, или
>   поставлено перед датой, **или отделено от даты частицей**, то наращения
>   уместны (числа 10-го, год 1980-й, с 19 мая по 20-е, в 20-х числах,
>   13-го же июня)...