# Буквенное наращение в датах типа «весной 2017» без года и месяца

Tags: наращение, даты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли буквенное наращение в датах типа «весной 2017» без года и месяца.

Знаю, что если слово год или месяц не стоит, либо стоит после числа, то наращение рекомендуется.

Верно ли написание в конструкциях такого типа:
весной 2017-го, осенью 1980-го, было лето 1920-го
(ведь ни года, ни месяца нет)?

И еще не совсем понятно: в июне 1941, в августе 2017 — почему нет наращения, ведь слово «год» опущено?

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

*Знаю, что если слово год или месяц не стоит, либо стоит после числа, то наращение рекомендуется.* — Что-то Вы тут напутали.

Если слово *год* или название месяца пропущено, то в порядковых числительных, обозначающих даты, требуется наращение.

Подготовка Бреста к 1000-летию начнется **весной 2017-го**...
Неприятности у авторов начались **осенью 1980-го**...
...«поход в Европу» был отложен до **лета 1920-го**.

Правильно:  в июне 1941-го, в августе 2017-го (слово год пропущено).

[Буквенные окончания (наращения) числительных](https://www.primavista.ru/blog/2017/01/06/narashheniya-chislitelnyih)
Подробнее на нашем сайте: [Наращения числительных в датах](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427002/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: Римма Михайловна, благодарю за разъяснение! Насчет весны, осени поняла, а вопрос про июнь 1941-го возник после этого комментария: «...в июне 41-го (если без тысяча девятьсот)» https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427002/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85

Comment: Что же Вас смутило? С тысяча девятьсот или без — дата все равно остается датой.

Comment: Поняла:) Меня просто смутило уточнение «если без тысяча девятьсот». Как будто если бы было это «тысяча девятьсот», то правило поменяется. А это просто пример был:) Разобралась, благодарю Вас!